# Changing the number of PE at run time in MPI

Tags: mpi, intel

I was wondering if it is possible to change the number of PE's at run time in MPI fortran using Intel Compilers. 
My problem is very specific and I would like to know if I can reduce the number of PE after I reach some point in my computation. 
My case is as follow: 
I have a code that crunches a lot of number. To solve huge problems I need around 128 PE's. But, when I finish my computation and I start printing the solution, the other 127 PE stay idle and this is a huge waste of resources. 
Is it possible to "deallocate" those 127 PE's when I am done with my computation and I still printing the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a straightforward way to achieve this.

A relatively simple option is to start your MPI app with one task, then `MPI_Comm_spawn()` 127 PEs, do your computation, terminates the 127 PEs and continue the serial part.

Generally speaking, such a 128 PE job is started via a resource manager, and imho, the real issue is whether the batch manager can support job shrink (iirc, SLURM does), and whether this is without any impact on MPI (this is a desired feature and PMIx has plans for that, but i have no idea whether SLURM supports this).

My best advice is to do things differently, and use MPI-IO to print your solution in parallel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I also believe that using the MPI-IO is the best option. I tried to implement that few months ago and it was a really challenging task since my partitions are differents. Each rank has its own size of arrays. I will try to go in that direction